# counting occurrences of end of line

Tags: c#, linq, string

I have some string with text, I want to count all occurrences of `Environment.NewLine`.

I thought to something in a way like

```
MyString.Where(c => c == Environment.NewLine).Count();
```

But `c` is only one char so it will not work .

Any better suggestions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Regex:

```
int count = Regex.Matches(input, Environment.NewLine).Count;
```

With String.Split:

```
int count = input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
                      StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1;
```

Comment: Mageed:Liked your Regex solution.